# Oracle pl/sql check if number starts with 9 or 8

Tags: oracle, validation

i am trying to validate data inside my database that is number.

Am i able to detect the retrieved data whether it starts with 8 or 9?

For example:

8999999 is valid

9999999 is valid

7000000 is invalid

Thanks

Comment: Your example numbers suggest you might mean that a number should consist solely of 8s and 9s.

Comment: How is this too broad? It would have been a perfect candidate for too localized when that was still a thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try checking the first character of the field using `SUBSTR()`:

```
SELECT field_value
FROM your_table
WHERE SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(field_value), 1, 1) IN ('8','9')
```

Comment: Although cost of both the answers is almost same, this one would be a tad bit faster. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The following query will return all records where column `data` begins with an `8` or `9`:

```
SELECT data
FROM your_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (CAST(data AS varchar2(30)), '^(8|9)(*)');
```

I assume here that `data` is a numeric type, and so I cast it to `varchar` before using `REGEXP_LIKE`.